# How to align the cells of one column with other columns in a responsive table?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a responsive table. The first column is only text value but other columns have text value and a button. While using hr tag, the misalignment of cells is quite visible. Here's a [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LnpUR6luc7Bdd2keZM0r?p=preview).

Is there any way to align the cells while keeping the table responsive? The following code isn't accurate.

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered hover col-sm-11 ">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>4</div><br>
      <div id="roomID1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showPopUp();">Book Now</button></div>
      <hr>
      <div>12</div><br>
      <div id="roomID2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showPopUp();">Book Now</button></div>
      <hr>
      <div>12</div><br>
      <div id="roomID2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showPopUp();">Book Now</button></div>
      <hr>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Align the cells how? Vertically centered with each other? The plunker doesn't include Bootstrap and the code is poorly formatted. Also the HR are impacting the alignment so do you intend to use them or did you all add them to visualize the alignment problem? Can you clean-up the code?

Comment: Is there a purpose for squeezing what is visually formatted as two cells, into one <td> cell syntactically? It would be easier to format if each visual cell was organized into it's own <td> tag.

Comment: @Zim hr tags will be used. So I want the hr tags for all columns to align, for a particular row. [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/JwuntvO.png).

[Is this better formatted?](https://plnkr.co/edit/mCOlC8u1CCS0664mEBoF?p=preview)

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss No particular purpose for the way it is now. I'll try to see if what you suggest will help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be having < td > for every cell as shown below and alignment would get fixed

```
<td>
    <div><strong>AC Room - 4 Bed<br>
    <font style="color:green;"> (Capacity:4 Person)</font><br>
    <font style="color:purple;"> (Charges: 1250 INR)</font><br>
    </strong><hr>
    </div>

</td>
<td>

    <div><strong>AC Room - Double Bed<br>
    <font style="color:green;"> (Capacity:2 Person)</font><br>
    <font style="color:purple;"> (Charges: 850 INR)</font><br>
    </strong><hr>
    </div>

</td>
```